# Variable being used without being initialized? C Language

Tags: c

I can't quite figure out what my issue is here. I keep getting an error in my code.

Error: Run-Time Check Failure: Variable used without being initialized.
: warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used

can someone help me solve this problem ? Any help would be appreciated.I'm using visual studio as a compiler for C and I'm a beginner in it and this is a one of the assignment. I don't see why  i keep getting  this issue if i input "int b;" in the beginning of the program. Wouldn't that variable be initialized?

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>


  //Create a program that asks the user to enter a number until the user enters a -1 to   stop
  int main() 
  {
   int b;

      //as long as the number is not -1,  print the number on the screen
 while(b!=-1) {
 printf("Hello there! would you please enter a number?");
 scanf(" %d",&b);

 //as long as the number is not -1,  print the number on the screen
 if(b!=-1){
 printf("Thank you for your time and consideration but the following %d you entered  wasn't quite what we expected. Can you please enter another?\n",b);

    //When the user enters a -1 print the message “Have a Nice Day :)” and end the program
 }else {
 printf("Have a Nice Day :), and see you soon\n");
 }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, C does not automatically initialize local variables for you, the programmer has to take care of that.

Comment: "Wouldn't that variable be initialized?" Whatever book you are using to learn C is not doing a very good job if it said that declaring a variable automatically initialized it.

Comment: Why can't this be detected at compile time instead of run-time?

Answer (score 11):

When you declare a variable, such as you have:

```
int b;
```

It is not initialised to have any value, it's value is unknown until you initialise it.

To fix this error, replace

```
int b;
```

With

```
int b = 0;
```

Comment: And actually, the value of `b` could be -1 or any other number.

Answer (score 4):

Error is here:

```
int main() 
  {
   int b;

      //as long as the number is not -1,  print the number on the screen
 while(b!=-1) {
```

Since you haven't initialized `b`, it can be anything. You then use it as a condition for `while` loop. This is very dangerous.

It may be that system randomly assign value of **`-1`** ( its a rare possibility ) to it .. in that case your `while` loop will not be actioned

Intialize `b` to some value

For eg do this:

```
int b = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing:

```
int b;
```

and then doing:

```
while(b!=-1) {
```

without ever initializing `b`. The problem is exactly what your warning is telling you it is.

C does not automatically initialize local variables for you, the programmer has to take care of that. `int b` allocates memory for your variable, but doesn't put a value in there, and it will contain whatever garbage value was in that memory prior to allocation. Your variable won't be initialized until you explicit assign, or another function explicitly assigns, a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int b;
```

is a variable declaration. Explicitly, the value is not initialized. The compiler will emit instructions for the program to reserve space to store an integer at a later time.

```
int b = 1;
```

this is a variable declaration with initialization.

```
int b;
while (b != -1)
```

this is use of an uninitialized variable, but so is

```
int a = rand() % 3; // so 'a' can be 0, 1 and or 2.
int b;
if (a == 0)
    b = 1;
else if (a == 1)
    b = 2;
printf("b = %d\n", b);
```

this is also a potential cause of uninitialized use of b. If 'a' is 2, we never assign a default value to b.

Upshot is you should always try to specify the default value with the declaration. If the logic that will determine initialization is complex, consider using an out-of-bounds value, as you are using -1.

Can you spot the bug in the following?

```
int b = -1;
if (a == 0)
    b = 1;
else if (a == 1)
    b = 2;
else if (a > 2)
    b = 3;

if (b == -1) {
     // this is an error, handle it.
}
```