# Run-time error, using undeclared variable, C++

Tags: c++, math, runtime

Im having this really weird error during run-time.
My program takes two parameters, does some math calculus with them and `std::cout`'s the values in the end.
My program works if i input somevalues, but if i input other values it says that a variable is being used without being initialized, which i think it makes no sence.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

double align_nb(int n) { return { ceil(n / 512.0)*512.0 }; }    // bytes
double align_pt(int k) { return { floor(k / 512.0)*512.0 }; }   // pointer

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int o_n = std::atoi(argv[1]);       // original number
    int o_p = std::atoi(argv[2]);       // original pointer

    int max_bytes, new_pointer;         // max bytes to read, new pointer to point


    float log = (std::log(o_n) / std::log(2));
    if (log != floor(log))
    {
        max_bytes = align_nb(o_n);      // bytes alinhados para a frente
        new_pointer = align_pt(o_p);    // ponteiro alinhado atrás
    }

    else if (log == floor(log))
    {
        new_pointer = align_pt(o_p);
        if (max_bytes + (o_p - new_pointer) >max_bytes)
        {
            max_bytes += 512;
        }
    }


    std::cout << "Original bytes= " << o_n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Original pointer= " << o_p << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max_bytes= " << max_bytes << std::endl;
    std::cout << "new_pointer= " << new_pointer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the values i tested it and it crashed, giving me that run-time error:

2048 513

1024 500

here is one example of values were the code doesnt give me that error and the program works:

513 520

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ODB.jpg) is a print of the error it gives me.

I'd really appreciate someone explaining me why it gives me that error/how to fix it.
Regardless, thanks!

(PS: math tag is included cause it could be the math in the program that is causing it to crash. If annyone thinks it shoudlnt be used in this question, let me know in the comments and ill remove it.)

(PS 2: the variable it complains when it gives me the run time error is 'max_bytes'.)

Comment: It does not say undeclared. It says uninitialized! Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602769/variable-being-used-without-being-initialized-c-language

Comment: @DavideSpataro what does that mean? How do i solve it? (thanks, i didnt noticed tat, ill edit)

Comment: Do not post links to code, paste them in your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your code takes the else path at line 17, then your code doesn't initialize `max_bytes`, but uses it afterwards. That's the problem.

Notes:

- comparing calculated floating point values for equality usually a bad practice
- you don't need the additional if at line 23.

Comment: what about this at line 13? int max_bytes, new_pointer;         // max bytes to read, new pointer to point

Comment: ohh i see, it has no values inside, i didnt notice that!

Comment: ill accept your awnser in 4minutes, thanks you solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that for each path your code takes the values of the variables you use are initialized. If you don't you get what is called Undefined Behaviour. There could be anything in an uninitialized variable.

```
int max_bytes;
....
....
expression_involving_max_byte <- Dangerous!
```